# Output of generic linked list has weird characters (?,n) and spaces C++

Tags: c++, linked-list, void-pointers

I'm writing a program for a homework assignment to create a generic linked list of class objects. The teacher requires us to use void pointers instead of templates, to implement a linked list of shells (yes, shells like you would inf on the beach, this dude is weird).

I'm writing the code to output the objects stored in the linked list to the console, and am getting some very strange output that I just can't figure out how to debug.

Here's the function in main to print to console

```
void printToConsole(Shell* newShell, LinkedList& shellList)
{
    do
    {
        newShell = static_cast<Shell*>(shellList.getNextNode()); 
        cout << "newShell " << newShell << endl;
        newShell->printToConsole();
    } while (shellList.getNextNode() != nullptr);

}
```

Here's the function in the linked list header to access the nodes that point to each class object:

```
void* LinkedList::getNextNode()
{
    if (curNode_ == nullptr)
    {
    curNode_ = first_;
    }

    while (curNode_ != nullptr)
    {
       curNode_ = curNode_->link_;
       return curNode_;
    }

    return nullptr;
}
```

And finally, here's the code in the Shell header to output the member variables:

```
void Shell::printToConsole()
{
    cout << name_ << ", " << taxonomy_ << ", " << mass_ << ", " << length_ << endl;
}
```

Now when I choose the option to print the list to the console, I'm seeing something like:

?7q     Paper FIg8q
                              Gastropoda08q 0.45P8q 33.4!?7q 9q??8q
Lace Murex?8q

The strange thing is, that all the text that should be outputted is there, there are just also all of these weird characters and formatting. I'm stumped. Hoping you all can point me in the right direction.

As requested, here is the header file of Shell class:

```
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Shell
{
private:
    string name_;
    string taxonomy_;
    string mass_;
    string length_;

public:

    Shell();
    void setName(string name);
    void setTaxonomy(string taxonomy);
    void setMass(string mass);
    void setLength(string length);
    void setMass(double mass);
    void setLength(double length);
    void printToConsole();
    void appendToFile();
};
```

And here is the implementation: (ignore the empty methods)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

#include "Shell.h"

using namespace std;

Shell::Shell()
{
    name_ = "";
    taxonomy_ = "";
    mass_ = "";
    length_ = "";
}
void Shell::setName(string name)
{
    name_ = name;
}
void Shell::setTaxonomy(string taxonomy)
{
    taxonomy_ = taxonomy;
}
void Shell::setMass(string mass)
{
    mass_ = mass;
}
void Shell::setLength(string length)
{
    length_ = length;
}
void Shell::setMass(double mass)
{

}
void Shell::setLength(double radius)
{

}
void Shell::printToConsole()
{
    cout << name_ << ", " << taxonomy_ << ", " << mass_ << ", " << length_ << endl;
}
void Shell::appendToFile()
{

}
```

More Edits:

Here's LinkedList.h:

```
struct Node
{
    void* data_;
    Node* link_;

    Node()
    {
        data_ = 0;
        link_ = 0;
    }
};

class LinkedList
{
private:
    Node* first_;
    Node* last_;
    Node* curNode_;
    long listLen_;

public:
    LinkedList();
    ~LinkedList();
    void addLinkToBack(void* ptr);
    void* removeLinkFromFront();
    void* getFirstNode();
    void* getNextNode();
    long getListLength();
};
```

And here's the implementation of LinkedList class: (Ignore output statements, they are for debugging)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

#include "LinkedList.h"

LinkedList::LinkedList()
{
    first_ = nullptr;
    last_ = nullptr;
    curNode_ = nullptr;
    listLen_ = 0;
}
LinkedList::~LinkedList()
{
    for (int i = listLen_; i > 0; i--)
    {
    removeLinkFromFront();
    }
}
void LinkedList::addLinkToBack(void* ptr)
{
    Node *newNode; //pointer of type node (struct)
    newNode = new Node; //create the new node
    std::cout << "newNode = " << newNode << std::endl;
    newNode->data_ = ptr; //newNode data pointer points to same memory address as ptr, which points to the current shell object
    std::cout << newNode-> data_ << std::endl;
    newNode->link_ = nullptr; //set link of newnode to null

    if (first_ == nullptr) //if first is nullptr, list is empty, first and last point to newnode
    {
        first_ = newNode;
        std::cout << "first_ = " << first_ << std::endl;
        last_ = newNode;
    }
    else //list is not empty
    {
        last_->link_ = newNode; //insert newnode at end of list
        last_ = newNode; //last now points to actual last node of list
    }

    listLen_++;

}
void* LinkedList::removeLinkFromFront()
{
    std::cout << "removeLinkFromFront called" << std::endl;
    Node *temp;

    if (first_ != nullptr) //while there are nodes in the list
    {
        temp = first_; //temp points to first node
        std::cout << "line 49" << std::endl;
        first_ = first_->link_; //first points to next node
        std::cout << "line 51" << std::endl;
        delete temp;
        std::cout << "line 53" << std::endl;
    }

    else if (first_ == nullptr) //list is empty
    {
        std::cout << "list is empty" << std::endl;
        last_ = nullptr;
        return nullptr;
    }

    listLen_--;
    std::cout << "list length = " << listLen_ << std::endl;

    return last_;
}
void* LinkedList::getFirstNode()
{
    return first_->data_;
}
void* LinkedList::getNextNode()
{
    if (curNode_ == nullptr)
    {
    curNode_ = first_;
    }

    while (curNode_ != nullptr)
    {
       curNode_ = curNode_->link_;
       return curNode_;
    }

    return nullptr;
}

long LinkedList::getListLength()
{

}
```

Comment: How do you initialize your LinkedList class, and it's fields?

Comment: See most recent edits. Thanks

Comment: So it looks like the printToConsole function within the Shell class is not working properly when it is called from the printToConsole function in the main file. The call is made properly, but for some reason, printToConsole in Shell tries to print the values of all of the member variables of the Shell objects within the linked list, instead of just printing the values for one Shell object, then passing control back to main. Any ideas on this one?

Answer (score 0):

I can see a problem with the line:

```
cout << "newshell" << newshell << endl;
```

Unless you have overloaded the Ostream operator, trying to log an object to the console is going to display garbage.

Replace that line with the following:

```
cout << "newshell" << endl;
```

...and compare the output.

Comment: I removed that line entirely, but the problem is still the same.

Comment: Can we please see the header file and implementation of the shell class?

Comment: You're welcome.  Looks like the issue is related to the input.  
Are you reading the data in from a file that was created on a different OS to that which you're using?  Carriage returns/new lines etc. can be handled differently depending on the OS.

Comment: I'm reading the input from a text file, created by the teacher. Not sure what OS he uses, but it could be different from mine. I'm running Ubuntu. However, I did copy/paste the text into a linux text editor and save to my desktop, which is where I am getting the input from.

Comment: Next step I would try is removing the newlines from one particular shell, then adding them again -both operations in your Ubuntu text editor.  I hope this is clear!

Answer (score 0):

There are two major problems:

1. In global `printToConsole`, result of `LinkedList::getNextNode` is directly
   cast to a `Shell*` and used as such. What `getNextNode` returns is not a pointer to node data (i.e. `Shell`), but it is a pointer to the beginning of `Node` object.

A working code will be:

```
Node* nextNode = static_cast<Node*>(shellList.getNextNode());
newShell = static_cast<Shell*>(nextNode->data_);
```

2. `getNextNode` skips every other node. This will cause error when list contains odd number of nodes.

---

For ref old answer below:

Check fields of `Shell` class, `name_`, `taxonomy_` etc.
What are their types, if they are `char*` you may have not
terminated them with `\0` properly.

Or there may be a problem with your linked list.
i.e. `link_` may point to uninitialized memory.

Comment: the member variables of Shell are all strings.

Comment: Link_ is initalized to zero when the node is created